# What number is midway between 2/4 and 3/4?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Sorry for posting this question but appreciate if you could help me.

What number is midway between 2/4 and 3/4?

Comment: Arithmetic mean of the two?

Comment: HINT: What is the midway between $4/8$ and $6/8$? (they are the same numbers)

Answer (score 2):

The number

$$\frac{\frac24+\frac34}2=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

suppose $b>a$, than we can find
the ''midway'' $c$ between $a$ and $b$ adding to $a$ half the distance between $a$ an $d$, that is the difference $b-a$. So

is $$c=a+\frac{b-a}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Using the arithmetic mean (i.e., $\frac{a+b}{2}$) with $\frac{2}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$. So, we'd get $\frac{\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}{2}$. Since the two fractions on the top have common denominators, we add to get $\frac{5}{4}$. Then, to divide by two, we can multiply by the reciprocal of 2, or $\frac{1}{2}$. Multiplying fractions is easy - just multiply the tops and then multiply the bottoms. We do $\frac{5}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ which gives $\frac{5}{8}$.
2. The other way to do this is by changing the denominators in the very beginning. $\frac{2}{4}$ is equal to $\frac{4}{8}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ is equal to $\frac{6}{8}$. From that point, it is clear to see that the fraction in the middle is $\frac{5}{8}$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at some measuring tape and look and the sixteenth hash-marks you can see that 10/16ths is in between 2/4 and 3/4